# Python string split - Attribute error

Tags: python

Why do I get the attribute error when tried to split the string `full_name` on space and assign it to two variables?

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, full_name):
        """Person initializer"""
        self.first_name, self.last_name = full_name.split()

    @property
    def first_name(self):
        return self.first_name

    @property
    def last_name(self):
        return self.last_name


if __name__ == '__main__':
    swadhi = Person("Swadhikar Chandramohan")
    print swadhi.first_name
    print swadhi.last_name
```

Error:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Users/swadhi/Documents/test/tutorial/inheritance.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/swadhi/Documents/test/tutorial/inheritance.py", line 18, in <module>
    swadhi = Person("Swadhikar Chandramohan")
  File "C:/Users/swadhi/Documents/test/tutorial/inheritance.py", line 6, in __init__
    self.first_name, self.last_name = full_name.split(' ')
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Comment: I think you need only `__init__` function that you already wriiten.

Comment: I advise your to do not add parsing code in `__init__`  instead call `swadhi = Person("Swadhikar Chandramohan")`  as `swadhi = Person("Swadhikar Chandramohan".split())`

Comment: @L_S: Thanks. That's the most apt answer for my question.!

Comment: Or provide a class method to parse: `Person.from_full_name('Swadhikar Chandramohan')`. But as pointed out below the issue is your properties are read only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not declare a setter of the property.
Thus the property is readonly and you can not modify it.

To solve it , add setter methods as follows:

```
@property
def last_name(self, value):
    self._last_name = value
@property
def first_name(self, value):
    self._first_name = value
@last_name.setter
def last_name(self, value):
    self._last_name = value
@first_name.setter
def first_name(self, value):
    self._first_name = value
```

Comment: Good answer, and for information, see the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) especially `The @property decorator turns the voltage() method into a “getter” for a read-only attribute with the same name`

Comment: Thank you @napuzba

Comment: This will work, but it would be more Pythonic to just drop the properties entirely since there no particular benefit to having them here.

Comment: In this simple case - Yes. However property is used to hide the implementation details from the outside world. In the future, the owner of the class can change the implementation details (i.e remove first_name attribute) without the users of the class have to change their code.

Comment: @napuzba but that's the point of properties. You can access the attribute directly until you need to not do so, then introduce a property **without changing the interface**. There is no benefit to putting them in before they do something other than a trivial get/set/delete, by contrast to the getters and setters in e.g. Java.

Answer (score 3):

No need of using `property` here

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, full_name):
        """Person initializer"""
        self.first_name, self.last_name = full_name.split()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    swadhi = Person("Swadhikar Chandramohan")
    print swadhi.first_name
    print swadhi.last_name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, full_name):
        """Person initializer"""
        self._first_name, self._last_name = full_name.split()

    @property
    def first_name(self):
        return self._first_name


    @property
    def last_name(self):
        return self._last_name

if __name__ == '__main__':
    swadhi = Person("Swadhikar Chandramohan")
    print swadhi.first_name
    print swadhi.last_name
```

As above, make sure a "_" prefixed at the property name when defining the class property.